# Stop overlay UIWindow from controlling the status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I'm creating a temporary UIWindow, on top of the main window, to show some small amount of data overlaid on the rest of my app. This information should not affect the status bar in any way. Note that the overlay window can be launched from a non-view controller context, meaning that the current view controller at the top of the stack of the main window might not be aware of the existence of the overlay window.

Unfortunately, as soon as I do `overlayWindow.isHidden = false`, it transfers control of the status bar (its style and whether it's hidden) to the root view controller of my overlay window, and I can't work out how to stop it.

Alternatively, I could just "remember" the previous state of the status bar and have my overlay root view controller output those, but there doesn't seem to be a good method to find out the current state and visibility of the status bar in iOS 13, at least which takes into account modally presented view controllers using the new sheet effect.

How can I have my overlay UIWindow reliably not affect the status bar?

---

**Edit:** I've prepared a small test case: https://github.com/Aquilosion/TestWindowView

The test case shows a view controller which changes its status bar appearance every second. You can open the same view controller again in a modal, and despite it also requesting status bar changes, iOS correctly locks the status bar white because the view controller never reaches it in sheet mode. Opening the window overlay currently always shows a black status bar, despite whether there's a modal presented or not. I attempt to set the status bar child to be the main window's root view controller's status bar child. Ideally, iOS would respect this and continue to change the status bar style while the overlay window was visible.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Coming across the exact same thing.

Comment: Not really, but I think for many use cases you could create some kind of 'layered view controller' as a window's root view controller, which itself can have various child view controllers, and additionally can be configured with which of its child view controllers gets to control the status bar (separately from what order the view controllers are in).

Answer (score 0):

You can override a property `childForStatusBarStyle` of the root view controller of the overlay window.

```
class YourRootController { // root of the overlay window

    var controllerToInheritStatusAttributesFrom: UIViewController?

    override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return controllerToInheritStatusAttributesFrom
    }

}


// Call this from any place of the app, where you show the overlay window
if let controller = overlayWindow.rootViewController as? YourViewController {
    controller.controllerToInheritStatusAttributesFrom = // needed controller, which lies underneath
    controller.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

I'm not sure it will help, considering that controllers will be in different windows, but it's worth a try.

[image]

I made your case work, just update the code:

```
private func updateStyle() {
    styleIndex += 1

    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    overlayWindow?.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Add this to MainViewController:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
     super.init(coder: coder)

     modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
 }
```

[image]

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if self.presentingViewController != nil {
            return .lightContent
        }
        return Self.styles[styleIndex % Self.styles.count]
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it works, either because you're not allowed to specify a view controller which isn't a child, or because it's not able to detect an existing iOS 13 sheet-style modal where the status bar becomes white, even when all the view controllers are wanting a black status bar.

Comment: @Robert, have you tried setting `rootViewControllerForOverlayWindow.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` ?

Comment: I don't think that works either. I've prepared a small test case, and updated my question with it. MainViewController.showOverlayWindow is responsible for showing the overlay window.

Comment: @Robert
I updated my answer. Now it work for .overFullScreen case

Comment: You forgot to call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate on a new controller.

Comment: Unfortunately that's got a few problems, because, 1: It requires the original view controller to know there's an overlay, which isn't always the case (I want to be able to use this method to show loading HUDs and alerts when there's no good pointer to a current view controller) and 2: It doesn't work if the original view controller is inside a modal (it's always black, where it should be always white). The second point is the main problem, as I'm not *that* concerned about keeping the status bar up-to-date, if I could only have a reliable way of determining what it currently is.

Comment: I'll update my question accordingly to make the constraints more clear.

Comment: @Robert
Actually, when you call `showOverlayWindow()` (without my additions), the status bar of OverlayViewController becomes the same color as MainViewController. If it was white, it becomes white, if it was black, it becomes black.

Comment: Yes, but that still doesn't work if the original view controller is presented inside a modal (click "Show Modal" first, and *then* "Show Overlay Window").

Comment: @Robert
Ah, I see

Comment: @Robert
Solved your case!

Comment: You need to set modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

Comment: To MainViewController

Comment: Hmm, testing it, it has the undesirable effect of not forcing the sheet style status bar to stay white, and it doesn't appear to affect the overlay window at all. Also ideally I'd want a solution which can be implemented without having to know the details of the main view controller (i.e. to show an overlay without having a context to the current view controller). I've updated my example project.

Comment: Unfortunately it's just making too many other problems, 1: I want the status bar to behave normally when doing a modal sheet, but here it's inheriting its parent one which is incorrect, and 2: It's requiring the main view controller to know about its overlay view controller, which is only really the case for this example: It needs to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` and set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance`, which isn't possible in practice because of the reasons I editing into my question. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @Robert
Actually, you can delete `overlayWindow?.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`, I did it just for testing reasons to change the color each second.

Comment: @Robert
I made one more update to keep the status bar white when presented modally, but then the Overlay presented on top also remains white. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Robert
I think even if it's not perfect, you know the tools (and ways) to make it work and then make the architecture smarter.

Comment: @Robert
Please, check out my test project: https://github.com/Ariandr/TestWindow

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look but I suspect there are too many trade-offs with this approach. Having said that, I'll probably have to accept there's no other way—I was really hoping there'd be a way to just select which `UIWindow` would control the status bar or something!